# How do you convert a dark matplotlib plot to a light grayscale for printing on a printer?

Tags: python, matplotlib, printing

I need to print a matplotlib plot on a printer using pyton 3 and PyQt5. My problem is that the plot has a dark background and colored traces and labels.That will take a lot of ink. I need to print the plot in black and white or gray scale and invert the dark colors to white or gray scale etc. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I believe the following documentation would be extremely helpful:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.style.use('grayscale')`. Alternatively, you can check out the other options with `print(plt.style.available)`